# Blender 2.8: Switching between Vertex/Edge/Face Selection?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, shortcut

How can I toggle between vertex, edge and face selection in *Edit Mode*?

[image]

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Its the <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd> keys above the letters (not the numbers pad)

Comment: Those hotkeys do not work on an MPB with the 2.8 official release, even with 'Emulate Numpad' disabled. Further there appears to be no way to switch selection modes through the menus. The three selection mode icons in the screen capture above are not displayed.

Comment: This saved my life. I hate how many unfixable UI issues blender has, like not showing the shortcut for these buttons when hovering over them like random other buttons happen to

Answer (score 22):

I'm using *Emulate Numpad*, and in this case <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd> are assigned to change views (front, side, ...), so these keys don't work anymore to toggle between vertex/edge and face select mode.

So what I did is change the hotkeys assigned to *vertex select mode*, *edge select mode* and *face select mode* to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>.

Here's how to do it:

1. go to *Edit > Preferences > Keymap*
2. Go to the field next to *Name* enter *Select Mode*

[image: search for select mode]

3. Now you should see under *Mesh* all the hotkeys for the different
   selection modes (for me, none of them works to toggle between
   vertex/edge/face select) I changed the first 3 to the keys that suit
   me, you can also choose different ones.

[image: original hotkeys for different selection modes]

4. To change the key, just click on the field on the right with the <kbd>1</kbd> for example, then it tells you to press the keys you would like to switch it to (I choose <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> which appears in the field as <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> but the key I press to go to *Vertex select mode* is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, so probably that's also because I use *Emulate Numpad*.

[image: changed hotkeys]

Comment: Many Thanks. I use Emulate Numpad and for me, 1, 3, 7, for switching views was so baked into my head that I left those as they were and thanks to your post have now got 2,4,6 for vertex/edge/face selection mode. Again, Many Thanks. Much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome :) I'm happy that it was helpful!! The only thing I realized recently is that with Blender 2.82, you can have edge/vertex/face select on at the same time! so I usually forget deactivating for example edge select when switching to vertex select, and loose some time there... but I guess I'll get used to that :D

Answer (score 3):

With respect to Blender 2.8(2018-12-02), using a Mac PowerBook, before the 1,2,3 buttons work...you must: Go to the Edit Menu >
Preferences > Uncheck 'Emulate Numpad'.

Hopefully, saves someone some time!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else was having an issue with these tools dissapearing all together, make sure you have only the object selected that you want to modify! I had multiple objects selected apparently and could not find the option to toggle the modes at all.

Answer (score 1):

Small remark, when you use numpad emulator and want to remap Selection Mode hotkey, better to remap with:
alt+1
alt+2
alt+3

because shift+.. already mapped with other selections modes and works incorrectly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/135705)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: to anyone reading the actual question and answers this answer makes sense! thankfully stack exchange has improved since the rather toxic attitudes previously