# I want the points back (Blender beginner)

Tags: modeling

So i am a beginner with blender and I want to make a donut but I have a problem.
This is what I have now:
[image]

But I want the points back:[image]

Is there any shortcut or something that I can use?

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "the points"? If you want to switch to vertex select mode, maybe check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120872/blender-2-8-switching-between-vertex-edge-face-selecttion

Comment: Just press 1 to go back to vertex select mode.(not numpad 1)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I mean the dots that you can select (those ones that become white when selected).

Comment: Thanks it worked.

Comment: Yeah that is called a vertex and press 1 to go to vertex select mode or click on the dot icon in the top left corner of the 3d viewport. Remember that you have to be in edit mode before pressing  1